# BlockCypher transaction failed status fetch

Tags: failed-transaction

At this moment we are developing mobile app and using BlockCypher.
Each completed transaction got 3 states: `success`/`failed`/`pending`.

We using link: https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#transaction-hash-endpoint
We write `success` if `confirmations` more than 2,
`pending` if <2
But how we can detect `failed` transactions?
Can't understand which field I can use for it?

Comment: What would you consider a failure?

Comment: Hi @Murch. For example check this hash:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x75b7ad2401800c85eb2558ae86d284f373e98b7baa0a23381ceebfe6343734c9
it got status failed.

Comment: Hi Sergey, we only talk about Bitcoin on this site. You will probably get a good answer on the Ethereum Stack Exchange for this topic!

Comment: Hi @Murch!) 
I'm asking abound bitcoin ) about block cypher usage ) etherscan I've post as example ) 
Or bitcoin can't get failed transactions?)

Comment: The only way that transactions in Bitcoin can "fail" is by being replaced with a conflicting transaction that spends some of the same inputs. Each input can only be spent once, so the original transaction would no longer be eligible for inclusion in the blockchain after the conflicting transaction got confirmed. As far as I understand, Ethereum blocks can include transactions that ran out of gas during evaluation i.e. they failed to conclude, but are part of the blockchain. This cannot happen in Bitcoin.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, @Murch!